# My sense home screen has stopped auto rotating, how do I fix it?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-desire-z, auto-rotation

I have a desire z (aka tmobile g2). When I fist got it a week ago the home screen used to rotate when the phone was tilted. It has since stopped doing that.

Other things still rotate when the phone is rotated. And the home screen rotates when I extend the keyboard. And menu -> settings -> display -> auto rotate screen is checked.

Comment: Hey.. I just noticed I have the same problem on my HTC Desire Z.. bizarre! Let me try holding the power button and selecting "restart".. nope, doesn't rotate anymore! Wow - I wonder if installing "Advanced Task Cleaner 2.0" is causing the problem...

Comment: I tried un-installing Advanced Task Cleaner, RockPlayer, WinAmp.. home screen still won't auto-rotate.

Comment: Are you *sure* it used to auto-rotate? I'm pretty certain the Sense / Rosie homescreen does not auto-rotate on any phone - it's just the slide-out keyboard that forces it.

Comment: Is there any major thing that you did? updating your OS perhaps? what is your android version?

Comment: @ Matthew Read: sorry to reply without a solution, but just to let you know: I too have the same issue, this is the first post I came across on the subject, and just to make sure you know this: the home screen did rotate without extending the keyboard, that much I can guarantee you. But just like with the others who posted here, after 2 days of usage it suddenly stopped auto-rotating, while other menus still do. I also noticed some lag in the Sense UI that wasn't previously there. Clean reboot, fiddling with the display rotation setting, recalibrating, uninstalling some software that had acces

Comment: I have the same problem.  Worked for 1 day, then stopped auto-rotating.
Help!

Comment: i have a similar problem as my desire-z prompted that the 'HTC sense is not working properly', either terminate it or wait. It happened when I return to the homescreen by pressing the home buttom after using the apps. it makes the auto-rotate very very slow too. I guess there must be some problems in the htc sense.....who can help???

Comment: I don't know about Sense UI, but in ADW.Launcher, setting ADW to be "System persistent" (prevent the system from killing the home screen) will also disable auto rotation.

Comment: Mine too stopped rotating.
I am sure that it did rotate wo the keyboard out: I have a car cradle and didn't have a problem rotating when docked. Now I do. Is this something to do with the recent update from HTC that supposed to fix camera issues?

Answer (score 1):

From everything I've read, it appears that the Desire Z version of Sense only rotates the homescreen when the keyboard is out.

You could try installing a custom ROM [like this one at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=860296) that supports rotation.